# Colspan attribute doesn't work with collapse

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a simple table with hidden rows that span the length of the table, but when I make the row appear the row is bound to one column despite it having `colspan="5"`.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<tbody><tr>
<th>Status</th>
<th>File</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Errors</th>
<th>Log</th>
</tr>

<tr><td>status</td><td>fileName</td><td>10</td><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr class="collapse info"><td colspan="5">This is a long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long message</td></tr>
<tr><td>status</td><td>fileName</td><td>10</td><td>2</td><td>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".info">Show Log</button></td></tr>

</tbody></table>
```

Link to sample code: http://www.bootply.com/9Re67hbLEf#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can just move the `class="collapse info"` to your `tr` instead of your `td`.

---

```
<tr><td class="collapse info" colspan="5">...</td></tr>
```

becomes

```
<tr class="collapse info"><td colspan="5">...</td></tr>
```

[Updated Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/D2gjToWq6R)

Comment: For some reason my question is also downvoted. This worked great, thank you! :)

Comment: I Upvoted you, don't really understand why you get downvoted ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
   add a div tag inside td and give class name "collapse info".It will work

 <table class="table table-hover">
        <tbody><tr>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>File</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Errors</th>
        <th>Log</th>
        </tr>

        <tr><td>status</td><td>fileName</td><td>10</td><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="5"><div class="collapse info">This is a long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long message</div></td></tr>
        <tr><td>status</td><td>fileName</td><td>10</td><td>2</td><td>

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".info">Show Log</button></td></tr>

        </tbody></table>
```

Comment: This is almost identical to the code in the question. Can you add an explanation to your answer to describe the subtle change made in this code that solves the question?

Comment: add a div tag inside td and give class name "collapse info".It will work